# VBA Filter Multiple Values then Send to New Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on a data where in I need to automate filtering then pasting to new sheet. However, I'm  not sure how to add another criteria for it.

```
    Dim sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim LstR As Long, rng As Range

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")    'set the sheet to filter
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")    'set the sheet to paste
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With sh    'do something with the sheet
        LstR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row    'find last row
        .Columns("D:D").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="UKS"
        Set rng = .Range("A2:Z" & LstR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)    'Replace Z with correct last column
        rng.Copy ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Try using Advanced Filter - The FASTEST way to Copy and Filter Data . tutorials at   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0YNhxVu2a5s

Comment: Hi, try to use Array filtering or Operator:=xlAnd. Full tutorial is [here](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/autofilter/)